# Custom Yes/No product attribute in template works on product page, but not on category page

Tags: product, category, attributes, template

I have a yes/no attribute used in product to output some text and it works fine:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('sale_text') == "Yes"): ?>
    <?php 
        $day = strtotime('friday this week'); 
        echo " - On Sale Through " . date('m/d/Y', $day); 
    ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, when outputting yes/no attribute label on the category page (list.phtml) with the following code, I'm getting a "No" for all products even though I have several products set as "Yes":

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('sale_text'); ?>
```

Any idea what the issue is and how to fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your custom attribute has not been enabled to display in the category page. Go to `Admin > Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes` and select the attribute. Then set the option for "Used in Product Listing" equal to `Yes`:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! That did the trick. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome. Please click the green accept icon under the vote up/down buttons! ☑️